# No object state info available while debugging in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I have just inherited an MVC 5 application to work on. I am trying to step through code to see the state of various objects that are involved in a given request to an action method. However, no information is available. I.e., if I type the ? in the immediate window, it says "could not evaluate expression". Also, when I hover over any variable, I get no tool tip with values as I normally would. Is there a setting in VS that would be causing this? I've never experienced this. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking the following option in Visual Studio:

Tools - Options - Debugging - General - Use Managed Compatibility Mode

For reference see [here](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Nov/21/Visual-Studio-2013-Could-not-evaluate-Expression-Debugger-Abnormality).